# openmp additional sync points with loop static scheduling

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, static, openmp

I am trying to understand more details regarding static scheduling for openmp parallel loops.

One question I came across when studying shared mem. programing with openmp.
Let's say I have a simple parallel loop:

```
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 4)
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; ++i)
    {
        arrR[i] = arrA[i] + arrB[i];
    }
```

48 iterations overall, 4 threads, chunk size = 4 iterations per thread.

Here is a diagram of static scheduling.

T - thread, C - chunk, S - synchronization point

| CYCLE1 (S1) | CYCLE2 (S2) | CYCLE3 (S3) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 T2 T3 T4 | T1 T2 T3 T4 | T1 T2 T3 T4 |
| C1 C2 C3 C4 | C1 C2 C3 C4 | C1 C2 C3 C4 |

Questions:

1. Is the diagram above correct?
2. Will we have 3 synchronization point in this case? Sync point 1 (S1) between CYCLE 1 and CYCLE 2, sync point 2 (S2) between CYCLE 2 and CYCLE 3, sync point 3 (S3) at the end? If yes, it will triple the synchronization overhead, right?

Thank you!

Comment: `static,4` means static with chunks of 4. Not 4 chunks. So you have 12 chunks, assigned to threads 123412341234 respectively. Your question would be more interesting if you have 46 iterations: then you would have an imbalance.

Comment: Regarding synchornization: with a static schedule there is none. Each thread knows in advance what iterations it does, so the only synchronization point is the barrier at the end.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout It seems to me that there is no synchronisation within OpenMP loop, whatever the scheduling: am I correct?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thanks! I wrote that there is a chunk size = 4 iterations per thread, it's not correct? I didn't write "4 chunks".

Comment: @VictorEijkhout If there is no synchronization inside the parallel loop, and if there is only one sync point at the very end of the loop, does it mean that: the threads are not waiting for each other between cycles? For example: CYCLE 1: T1(1 sec), T2(2 sec), T3(2 sec), T4(2 sec). What will happen? T1 is not waiting for T2, T3, and T4 within CYCLE 1, and once finished, immediately jumps to the chunk 1 in CYCLE 2? I am asking because there are some lectures that say opposite. According to lectures, the threads DO wait for each other between CYCLES in the case of static block cyclic scheduling.

Comment: @Base0 could you point to such lectures? There's nothing like "cycles" in practice. In your exemple, the thread 0 will execute the iterations 0-1-2-3-16-17-18-19-32-33..., the thread 1 will execute the iterations 4-5-6-7-20-21-... and so on. I can't see a good reason with sync points would be needed... It's possible that some implementations do so, but it's not required by the OpenMP specification AFAIK.

Comment: @PierU Sure. Let me provide the links.

Comment: lec1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjCFT5ojQSk timing: 2:13:00

Comment: lec2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDNvXCt7t0M timing: 14:44

Comment: In the lecture 1, the speaker explicitly mentioned term "cycle" and even named this sort of scheduling, schedule(static, 4) for example as "block cyclic schedule"

Comment: In the lecture 2, it was mentioned about additional sync points within the parallel loop in the case of schedule(static, chunkSize)

Comment: I can't spot where additional sync points are mentioned in the 2nd video. Anyway, it's not difficult to write a program that shows that the only sync point is at the end of the loop (here in Fortran, but OpenMP behavior is the same): https://godbolt.org/z/ea78oKehh

Comment: "block cyclic" does not mean that there are cycles. For schedule `static` there are no synchronization points, other than the final barrier. For `dynamic,guided` there are also none, but the runtime assigns the chunks dynamically, which you could consider some form of synchronization.

Comment: @Base0 That archer video is good, but you misunderstand it. It says iterations are assigned cyclically, which means it1->thread1, 2->2, 3->3, 4->4, and the 5->1, 6->2. There are no cycles in the execution. Like I said, with `static`, each thread knows which iterations it's going to do, and it does those without ever synchronizing except at the end. You'll note that the video does not say anything about synchronization.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout , and PierU thanks very much guys for being patient with me and answering my question(s)! I think, I realized my misunderstanding and now it becomes clearer. Actually I was caught by the term "cycling" from 1st video on YouTube. The chunks of iterations are assigned to threads (or scheduled for threads) cyclically - yes, but then executed according to the previously established schedule kind of linearly without any intermediate delays. The barrier sync is at the end of the loop only.

Comment: Chapter 8 ("Scheduling Parallel Loops") in our book ("High Performance Parallel Runtimes" https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110632729/html ) discusses parallel loop scheduling both from a theoretical viewpoint ("What does the mathematics say is the best you can ever do?") and an implementation point of view. (You can see the actual implementation code for a small OPenMP runtime at https://github.com/parallel-runtimes/lomp . If you want to go deeper that may help!